# momentjs daylight saving time after 2038

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I am using moment-timezone in a AngularJS application. I'm facing a problem that I do not understand despite reading the 'Timezone' tag wiki.

I wish to have an event that repeats itself every year: same day, same time. 
I have an object for each of these events with a start date and an end date.
My timezone is

```
moment.tz.guess() : 'Europe/Paris'
```

Before 2038 I have no problem with the dates

```
moment.unix(date.start).format(); : 2018-06-19T14:16:07+02:00
moment.tz(moment.unix(date.start), 'Europe/Paris').format(); : 2018-06-19T14:16:07+02:00
moment.unix(date.start).isDST(); : true

moment.unix(date.start).format(); : 2019-06-19T14:16:07+02:00
moment.tz(moment.unix(date.start), 'Europe/Paris').format(); : 2019-06-19T14:16:07+02:00
moment.unix(date.start).isDST(); : true

moment.unix(date.start).format(); : 2020-06-19T14:16:07+02:00
moment.tz(moment.unix(date.start), 'Europe/Paris').format(); : 2020-06-19T14:16:07+02:00
moment.unix(date.start).isDST(); : true
```

but after 2037 the offset is "+01:00" instead of "+02:00" if I deal with Timezone and ... don't understand why :

```
moment.unix(date.start).format(); : 2035-06-19T14:16:07+02:00
moment.tz(moment.unix(date.start), 'Europe/Paris').format(); : 2035-06-19T14:16:07+02:00
moment.unix(date.start).isDST(); : true

moment.unix(date.start).format(); : 2036-06-19T14:16:07+02:00
moment.tz(moment.unix(date.start), 'Europe/Paris').format(); : 2036-06-19T14:16:07+02:00
moment.unix(date.start).isDST(); : true

moment.unix(date.start).format(); : 2037-06-19T14:16:07+02:00
moment.tz(moment.unix(date.start), 'Europe/Paris').format(); : 2037-06-19T14:16:07+02:00
moment.unix(date.start).isDST(); : true

moment.unix(date.start).format(); : 2038-06-19T14:16:07+02:00
moment.tz(moment.unix(date.start), 'Europe/Paris').format(); : 2038-06-19T13:16:07+01:00
moment.unix(date.start).isDST(); : true

moment.unix(date.start).format(); : 2039-06-19T14:16:07+02:00
moment.tz(moment.unix(date.start), 'Europe/Paris').format(); : 2039-06-19T13:16:07+01:00
moment.unix(date.start).isDST(); : true
```

do you have any suggestion? thanks

Comment: I suspect that moment.js is using transition tables that are only generated as far as 2038.

Comment: Thx for the reply, do you know how I can verify that ?

Comment: The closest I know of is https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-utilities/: "By default, Moment Timezone includes all the data from the IANA Time Zone Database. This includes data from 1900 to 2038."

Comment: @DaisyShipton thx for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Nobody* can reliably tell you what the time zone offset or DST rules will be in 2038.  Even projecting to just tomorrow is based on blind faith that the governments won't change the rules before then.

Indeed it has happened that some of them have changed the rules under very short notice, or overnight and told people after the fact.  See [On the Timing of Time Zone Changes](https://codeofmatt.com/2016/04/23/on-the-timing-of-time-zone-changes/).

Most of the time, the world find outs in advance, the [tz mailing list](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) gets wind of it and releases a tzdb update, then libraries like Moment-Timezone (and many others) take in this information and process it into their own formats.

Moment-timezone's particular format takes recurrence rules and projects them into specific deltas for each transition.  This has a speed advantage at runtime, but has the disadvantage of not being able to go on and on forever.  Given that the unpredictability of future changes increases exponentially over time, this was a reasonable compromise by the designers of this library (IMHO).

Comment: It's clear, thank you.
Concerning the possible change of rules it's about endless debate and in the same time there are currently rules for daylight saving time without limitation in the time for their application.

I understand the choice made for performance, I will implement my feature differently

Thank you for the help and answer.